# Compile with java 1.8 for Tomcat7?

Tags: java, tomcat

It is possible to compile a project with installed `1.8` sdk with `JDK Compiance` set to `1.7`, and install the `war` file on a `Tomcat7` machine where also java `1.8` is installed?

Or would I always have to compile those projects with java `1.7` for tomcat7?

Comment: Java 1.8 will run 1.7 compliant programs.  1.8 can run anything <= 1.8 but nothing > 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 claims to support Java 6 "and later", which would include Java 8 in theory.

See [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page for release compatibility information.

Note: Java 7 compliance implies your code is checked against Java 7 syntax (e.g. no lambdas). This means it can be run with JVMs from version 7 and above.